# Storing data in memcache to be accessed by different languages

Tags: c#, php, c++, python, memcached

I am working on a system that has components written in the following languages:

- C
- C++
- C#
- PHP
- Python

These components all use (infrequently changing) data that comes from the same source and can be cached and accesed from memcache for performance reasons.

Because different data types may be stored differently by different language APIs to memcache, I am wondering if it would be better to store ALL data as string (objects will be stored as JSON string).

However, this in itself may pose problems as strings (will almost surely) have different internal representations accross the different languages, so I'm wondering about how wise that decision is.

As an aside, I am using the 1 writer, multiple readers 'pattern' so concurrency is not an issue.

Can anyone (preferably with ACTUAL experience of doing something similar) advice on the best format/way to store data in memcache so that it may be consumed by different programming languages?

Comment: Any JSON (or any data interchange format) (de)serializer will probably know how to work with a stream of characters / bytes of a known character encoding, and "finite stream of bytes" has the same representation anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

memcached I think primarily only understands byte[] and representation of byte is same in all languages. You can serialize your objects using [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or a similar library and consume it in any other language. I've done this in my projects.

Comment: Looks like protocol buffers doesn't have a binding for PHP (or C#). I suppose I could write SWIG wrappers aroung PB - but I'm not sure if I want to take on that task, especially if a simpler solution exists...

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the back-end chosen, (memcached, mongodb, redis, mysql, carrier pigeon) the most speed-efficient way to store data in it would be a simple block of data (so the back-end has no knowledge of it.) Whether that's `string`, `byte[]`, `BLOB`, is really all the same.

Each language will need an agreed mechanism to convert objects to a storable data format and back. You:

- Shouldn't build your own mechanism, that's just reinventing the wheel.
- Should think about whether 'invalid' objects might end up in the back-end. *(either because of a bug in a writer, or because objects from a previous revision are still present)*

When it comes to choosing a format, I'd recommend two: [JSON](http://json.org%20JSON) or [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html). This is because their encoded size and encode/decode speed is among the smallest/fastest of all the available encodings.

### Comparison

**JSON:**

- Libraries available for dozens of languages, sometimes part of the standard library.
- Very simple format - Human-readable when stored, human-writable!
- No coordination required between different systems, just agreement on object structure.
- No set-up needed in many languages, eg PHP: `$data = json_encode($object); $object = json_decode($data);`
- No inherent schema, so readers need to validate decoded messages manually.
- Takes more space than Protocol Buffers.

**Protocol Buffers:**

- Generating tools provided for several languages.
- Minimal size - difficult to beat.
- Defined schema (externally) through `.proto` files.
- Auto-generated interface objects for encoding/decoding, eg C++: `person.SerializeToOstream(&output);`
- Support for differing versions of object schemas to add new `optional` members, so that existing objects aren't necessarily invalidated.
- Not human-readable or writable, so possibly harder to debug.
- Defined schema introduces some configuration management overhead.

### Unicode

When it comes to Unicode support, both handle it without issues:

- JSON: Will typically escape non-ascii characters inside the string as `\uXXXX`, so no compatibility problem there. Depending on the library, it may be also possible to force UTF-8 encoding.
- Protocol Buffers: Seem to use UTF-8, though I haven't found info in Google's documentation in 3-foot-high letters to that effect.

### Summary

Which one you go with will depend on how exactly your system will behave, how often changes to the data structure occur, and how all the above points will affect you.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to lie you could do it in redis. [Redis](http://redis.io/) is a key-value database written to be high performance it allows the transfer of data between languages using a number of different client libraries [these are the client libraries](http://redis.io/clients) Here is an example in java and python

Edit 1: Code is untested. If you spot an error please let me know :)

Edit 2: I know I didn't use the prefered redis client for java but the point still stands.

Python

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis()
r.set('test','123')
```

Java

```
import org.jredis.RedisException;
import org.jredis.ri.alphazero.JRedisClient;
import static org.jredis.ri.alphazero.support.DefaultCodec.*;

class ExampleCode{
    private final JRedisClient client = new JRedisClient();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RedisException {
        System.out.println(toStr(client.get('test')))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an in-memory database?. The whole idea of cacheing in a central repository was to bypass the disk/IO bottleneck.

Comment: You can change it to never write to drive :) Just one little .conf line

Comment: Will It improve the writing speed? I heard Redis has lower writing speed relative to the Memcached

Comment: It should only then write to memory (I think like a socket), and that's getting improved in the next version of redis